# using *tables* as Table-Valued Parameters (TVP)

Tags: sql-server-2008

MS SQL 2008 supports TVP: a useful feature for bulk uploading data to a stored proceedure for processing.

Rather than create a user-defined type, is it possible to leverage an existing table definition?  For example, is it possible to create a stored proceedure with the following signature?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_InsertProductionLocation
@TVP **LocationTable** READONLY
```

The documentation seems to suggest that this is not possible.

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
/*
Sample code from:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx
*/

USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO

/* Create a table type. */
CREATE TYPE LocationTableType AS TABLE 
( LocationName VARCHAR(50)
, CostRate INT );
GO

/* Create a procedure to receive data for the table-valued parameter. */
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_InsertProductionLocation
    @TVP LocationTableType READONLY
    AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    INSERT INTO [AdventureWorks2008R2].[Production].[Location]
           ([Name]
           ,[CostRate]
           ,[Availability]
           ,[ModifiedDate])
        SELECT *, 0, GETDATE()
        FROM  @TVP;
        GO

/* Declare a variable that references the type. */
DECLARE @LocationTVP 
AS LocationTableType;

/* Add data to the table variable. */
INSERT INTO @LocationTVP (LocationName, CostRate)
    SELECT [Name], 0.00
    FROM 
    [AdventureWorks2008R2].[Person].[StateProvince];

/* Pass the table variable data to a stored procedure. */
EXEC usp_InsertProductionLocation @LocationTVP;
GO

/*
The following is not part of the original source code:
*/

CREATE TABLE LocationTable(
 LocationName VARCHAR(50)
, CostRate INT );
GO
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, you can't leverage an existing table definition, you need to define an explicit type. This was asked for back in 2007 and was closed as "won't fix" but I still strongly encourage you to up-vote and leave a comment describing your use case and how this will help your business be more productive. You could even point to this question to demonstrate how tedious it can be to try and automate this.

- [Declare a variable...(Formerly UserVoice #32891356 (Formerly Connect #294130))](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/46e936d1-4c25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0)

You can do this today, dynamically, though... for example for your simple definition:

```
-- you would pass these two in as parameters of course:
DECLARE
  @TableName SYSNAME = N'LocationTable',
  @TypeName  SYSNAME = N'LocationTypeTable';

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql = @sql + N',' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(9) 
    + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ' '
    + s.name + CASE WHEN LOWER(s.name) LIKE '%char' THEN 
        '(' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), (c.max_length/
        (CASE LOWER(LEFT(s.name, 1)) WHEN N'n' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END))) + ')' 
        ELSE '' END
        -- need much more conditionals here for other data types
    FROM sys.columns AS c
    INNER JOIN sys.types AS s
    ON c.system_type_id = s.system_type_id
    AND c.user_type_id = s.user_type_id
    WHERE c.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@TableName);

SELECT @sql = N'CREATE TYPE ' + @TypeName
    + ' AS TABLE ' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + '(' + STUFF(@sql, 1, 1, '')
    + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + ');';

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Results:

```
CREATE TYPE LocationTypeTable AS TABLE 
(
    [LocationName] varchar(50),
    [CostRate] int
);
```

Disclaimer: This does not deal with all kinds of other things like MAX types, precision and scale for numerics, etc. The final solution would have to be more robust to account for all potential column definitions but this should give you a start.

In SQL Server 2012 there are new DMVs and stored procedures that will make it much easier to derive column metadata from existing tables (or stored procedures or even ad hoc queries) without having to mess with all the conditional logic against sys.types and sys.columns. I [blogged briefly about these enhancements in December](https://sqlblog.org/2010/12/20/sql-server-v-next-denali-metadata-enhancements). It's still tedious, but it's somewhere between the awful unmaintainable spaghetti above and the ability to just say " as copy of [table x]"...

Answer (score 4):

I dealt with this issue by creating following stored procedure to create a type with same schema existing table may have.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_DefineTypeOutOfTableSchema] --or e.g. usp_DefineTypeFromTable
@TableNames NVARCHAR(500)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @strSQL NVARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @strSQLCol NVARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @ColName NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @ColDataTaype NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @ColDefault NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @ColIsNulable NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @ColFirst NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @ColSecond NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @ColID NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @ColCompute NVARCHAR(50)

IF LEN(@TableNames) > 0 SET @TableNames = @TableNames + ',' 
WHILE LEN(@TableNames) > 0 
    BEGIN
        SELECT @TableName = TRIM(LEFT(@TableNames, CHARINDEX(',', @TableNames) - 1))
        DECLARE schemaCur CURSOR FOR 
            SELECT 
                c.name as column_name,
                t.name as [type_name],
                c.is_nullable,
                convert(nvarchar(4000), object_definition(ColumnProperty(c.object_id, c.name, 'default'))) as column_default,
                CASE
                    WHEN c.collation_name IS NOT NULL THEN c.max_length 
                    WHEN t.name like 'datetime%' THEN c.scale
                    WHEN c.scale = 0 THEN NULL
                    ELSE c.precision
                END as firstValue,
                CASE
                    WHEN (c.scale = 0 or t.name like 'datetime%') THEN NULL
                    ELSE c.scale
                END as secondValue,
                c.is_identity, -- would be best to know seed,increment
                c.is_computed -- should really look up col definition. `convert(nvarchar(4000), object_definition(ColumnProperty(c.object_id, c.name, 'computed')))` as computed ?

            FROM sys.columns as c join 
                 sys.all_objects as o 
                    on c.object_id=o.object_id join
                 sys.types as t
                    on c.user_type_id=t.user_type_id
            WHERE
                o.type in ('U','V','TF','IF','TT') and --'S' to include built-in tables/types
                o.name = @TableName
            ORDER BY o.name, c.column_id
        OPEN schemaCur
        SELECT @strSQL=''
        FETCH NEXT FROM schemaCur
            INTO @ColName,@ColDataTaype,@ColIsNulable,@ColDefault,@ColFirst,@ColSecond,@ColID,@ColCompute
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
--            SELECT @strSQLCol=''
            SELECT @strSQLCol= '['+@ColName+'] '+'[' + @ColDataTaype +'] '
            IF @ColSecond is NULL
                BEGIN
                    IF @ColFirst is not NULL SELECT @strSQLCol += '(' + @ColFirst + ') '
                END 
            ELSE SELECT @strSQLCol += '(' + @ColFirst +',' +@ColSecond + ') '
            IF @ColID>0 SELECT @strSQLCol += ' IDENTITY(1,1)'
            IF @ColIsNulable>0 SELECT @strSQLCol += 'NULL'
                ELSE SELECT @strSQLCol += ' NOT NULL'
            IF @ColDefault IS NOT NULL SELECT @strSQLCol += ' DEFAULT(' +@ColDefault + '),'
                ELSE SELECT @strSQLCol += ','
            SELECT @strSQL += @strSQLCol
                --print @strSQL
            FETCH NEXT FROM schemaCur
            INTO @ColName,@ColDataTaype,@ColIsNulable,@ColDefault,@ColFirst,@ColSecond,@ColID,@ColCompute
        END

        CLOSE schemaCur
        DEALLOCATE schemaCur

        SELECT @strSQL=left(@strSQL, len(@strSQL)-1)

        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.types WHERE IS_TABLE_TYPE = 1 AND name = 'tt_' +@TableName)
        BEGIN           
            EXEC('DROP TYPE tt_' +@TableName )
        END

        SELECT @strSQL = 'CREATE TYPE tt_' + @TableName + ' AS TABLE (' +  @strSQL + ')'
        -- print @strSQL
        EXEC (@strSQL)
        SELECT @TableNames = SUBSTRING(@TableNames, CHARINDEX(',', @TableNames) + 1, LEN(@TableNames))
    END
END
```

you can use it like this

Exec Sp_DefineTypeOutOfTableSchema 'Table1name,Table2name'

Comment: This code didn't work for me. "User-defined functions, partition functions, and column references are not allowed in expressions in this context." Even if it did work, it doesn't look like there is anything to handle schemas other than dbo.

Answer (score 3):

Erland Sommarskog has [an extensive article](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html) describing how to use TVP.

Have a look, it's worth it!

In short, you cannot use an existing type, just like Aaron Bertrand's earlier [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/12603/3046). But at least it's a bulk transfer..